# Build phase that create a Plist and copy it in resource bundle

Tags: xcode

I've made a ruby script that generate a Plist from data in other format (This script is inside the xcode's project folder).

I've made a custom run script build phase that call my script:

```
echo "Running xls Plister"
cd ${PROJECT_DIR}/plistr
ruby plistr.rb
scriptExitStatus=$?
echo "DONE with script: (exitStatus=${scriptExitStatus})"
exit "${scriptExitStatus}"
```

This script output the plist in the following folder `${PROJECT_DIR}/plistr/output/data.plist`

What I can't figure out is how to copy this in the Bundle resource so i can access it with something like this:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
```

EDIT: my actual workaround is to run the script as first build step and manually add the reference to the generated plist in "Copy Bundle Resources"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can copy a file to the bundle this way:

```
cp /tmp/foo.txt ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
```

Please notice, copying the **info.plist** to the bundle is not recommended, it will also produce a warning if copied with the Copy Bundle Resources build phase.

Look at [this official statement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1649/_index.html).

Comment: Could please fix the link to the "official statement", this seems not to be a valid link to anything. Thank you.

Comment: That article says its only bad to copy the app's Info.plist file, not plists (like dynamically generated plists like what OP is doing)

Comment: @NickWeaver I have something similar to what you have that copies files to a .app file before I produce a store or adhoc build. However, it seems that doing so corrupts the file and you cannot install it on the phone (it'll say the app cannot be installed). Did you run into this issue?

Comment: @kevinl No sorry, but look at the date of the answer, it may as well be outdated and not possible anymore.

Comment: @NickWeaver thanks. I figured it out.

I created a folder named "Cached" under my Resources folder. I dragged the "Cached" folder into xcode (initially empty) but when the "Files & Groups" option shows up, you check the "Create folder references for any added for any folders". From there everything should be good to go.

I copy the cached images using a basic shell script to the newly created "Cached" folder so the folder will add any resource that was placed in there during build time :)